# Receiving array form data as JSON sent by jQuery and received by Node Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I am playing around with Node Js and I have been building an app as a learning process, in this app I want to send data from a HTML form via a jQuery/AJAX and have Node Js/Express receive and process the data.

HTML is below with a series of these input groups:

```
<form action="/nodeRoute" method="post" id="myFormID">
<div class="input-group col-xs-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="field1[]" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="field2[]" />
</div>
</form>
```

On the jQuery end I am sending the data like so:

```
$('#myFormID').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('#myFormID').serializeArray();

    // Send AJAX request.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/nodeRoute",
        data: JSON.stringify({formData}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Success');
        },
        failure: function(err) {
            console.log("Failure", err);
        }
    });
});
```

On the node end I am using `router.use(bodyParser.json());` and outputting `console.log(req.body.formData);`. What I get is the below:

```
[ { name: 'field1[]', value: '12' },
{ name: 'field1[]', value: '34' },
{ name: 'field2[]', value: '56' },
{ name: 'field2[]', value: '78' } ]
```

What I would like is:

```
[ { field1: [12,34], field2: [56,78] } ]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: I have amended the original post to include an example of the form being used.

Comment: What is the format of sent data? I mean how does the request data look?

Comment: You cannot get an array of values, what you can get is field[1]=10, field[2]=20 etc.

Comment: If you really want the way you have been asking for then you need to do it manually, if you are fine with the approach I can go ahead and write the JS for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build the data in the format you require you would need to do it manually by looping through the elements of the form and setting the keys and values in an object. Try this:

```js
var formData = {};
$('#myFormID .form-control').each(function() {
  var fieldName = this.name.replace(/\[\]/g, '');
  if (!formData[fieldName])
    formData[fieldName] = [];    
  formData[fieldName].push(this.value);
});

console.log(formData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/nodeRoute" method="post" id="myFormID">
  <div class="input-group col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="field1[]" value="12" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="field2[]" value="34" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-group col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="field1[]" value="56" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="field2[]" value="78" />
  </div>
</form>
```

From there you can just provide the resulting object to the `data` property of `$.ajax`. You don't need to stringify it as jQuery will do that for you:

```
// Send AJAX request.
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/nodeRoute",
    data: formData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success');
    },
    failure: function(err) {
        console.log("Failure", err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was something built in to get me the data in this format but your snippet has worked.

Comment: Unfortunately not as serializeArray() builds an object per input element, it doesn't group them together. Glad to help

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would do it:

```js
// your node backend

req.body.field.split(' '); // => [ 12, 32, ... ]
```

```html
<!-- your html -->

<input type="text" name="field">
```